# Enable layer GeoTIFF

Tags: geoserver

Via API, conversely, something goes wrong.
To create new Workspace, new coverageStore, and GEoTiff Layer i'm using this URL

```
https://...../geoserver/rest/workspaces/ww-acgs-1/coveragestores/ww-acgs-1-store/file.geotiff?filename=ww-acgs-1-title&coveragename=ww-acgs-1-layer
```

The url above produces for me the same result as you can see in the attached pics: disable layer with empty native SRS.

[image]

[image]

If there's no way to enabled it during creation, i I thought to edit layer after creation itself...
To do it, i'm using the URL below

```
https://...../geoserver/rest/workspaces/ww-acgs-1/datastores/ww-acgs-1-store/featuretypes/ww-acgs-1-layer

{
   featureType:{
    overridingServiceSRS: true,
    srs: "EPSG:4326",
    enabled: true
  }
}
```

But the error caught is:

```
"error": {
  "name": "GeoServerResponseError",
  "geoServerOutput": "No such data store: ww-acgs-1,ww-acgs-1-store"
}
```

Something makes me think that featuretypes is a wrong endpoint to edit a geoTiff Layer, because they are two different types of layer, i guess.

So, my qeustions after that are:

- Can i create, directly, a geoTiff layer with right settings for "enable" and "srs" key?
- if not, can I edit GeoTiff Layer after its creation and with which url and params...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the actual URL you are using, does it work if you add it via the GUI?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.